# "startIndex" of Recharts Brush does not change even though using setState and state was changed

Tags: reactjs, setstate, use-state, recharts

I want change startIndex using button, but it does not work.

```
const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);
...
<Brush dataKey="date" startIndex={startIndex} />
...
<Button onClick = { () => setStartIndex(30) } > Change </Button>
```

When checking using useEffect as shown below, the variable changed properly.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(startIndex)
}, [startIndex])
```

> 0    // first rendered

> 30   // button clicked

It works only the size of window changed. Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your data!

```
<Brush dataKey="date" startIndex={startIndex} data={...data}/>
```